# AVAssetImageGenerator gives low resolution images

Tags: ios, avfoundation

From a video I would like to extract the image shown to the user at some specific time (e.g: What the user is seeing at second 2 for example).

I used AVAssetImageGenerator's copyCGImageAtTime:actualTime:error: but the image that I get has low resolution (you feel like it was taken by some really old camera). I guess the reason is that at each second there is mutiple frames and not only one.

So how can I get better resolution ?

Comment: can you show the code you're using to extract the images?

Comment: I just call [generator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime nil :error nil]

Comment: You cannot "see" a CGImage so how do you know what the image looks like? In other words, what is your actual code for extracting and _viewing_ the image?

Comment: I got your point. After creating the CGImage I convert back to UIImage and save to camera roll using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);